# Django IntegrityError, get error number or code

Tags: python, django

I want to check for `IntegrityError(1048, "Column 'ean' cannot be null")`. 
What is the proper way to do this? I feel like I'm not using the best method.

Product class

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ean = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

Currently I'm doing this crazy trick.

```
newProduct = Product(ean=None, name='Foo')

try:
    newProduct.save()
except IntegrityError, e:
    error = e

code = error.__getslice__(0,1)
code = error[0]

# handle error 1048
```

I would love to see a proper example of handling a specific IntegrityError in Python / Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a method to validate the product object before saving it. This way I'm sure that I can save the product without running into errors. Thanks for the tips!

For more information see that [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) on validating objects.

```
class Product(model.Models):

    def saveProduct(self, product):
        if self.validateProduct(product):
            product.save()


    def validateProduct(self, product):
        try:
            product.full_clean()
        except ValidationError:
            return False

        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is not to handle the `IntegrityError` but to validate the model instance before saving it:

```
# Run validation
try:
    newProduct.full_clean()
except ValidationError as error:
    error.error_dict  # A dictionary mapping field names to lists of ValidationErrors.
    error.message_dict  # A dictionary mapping field names to lists of error messages.

    # In your case you can check
    for e in error.error_dict.get('ean'):
        if e.code == 'blank':
            # ean was empty
```

Answer (score 1):

IntegrityError exception handling is little different ,So to fetch number.

```
e.args[0]
```

For more information : https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/5321/MySQLdb.IntegrityError

Answer (score 0):

Django has some optional parameters for checking content of fields such as `null` and `blank` for checking that field is not empty, so has some [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/) that you can use for checking content of fields for example use django `MinLengthValidator` for checking length of `ean` field content:

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

class Product(models.Model):
    ean = models.BigIntegerField(null=False, validators=MinLengthValidator(1, message='The "ean" field min length is one char at least.'))
    name = models.CharField()
```

By using `MinLengthValidator` you can return custom message if `ean` field is empty.

Comment: Model fields don't have a `required` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Field ean is an required field,you cannot pass None value into it.To fix this issue add

```
ean = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Then it wont show integrity error.Becuase right now the field is expecting some data not null value.

Otherwise

```
 newProduct = Product(ean=256, name='Foo')
```

pass an integer value.This worked for me.

You can also right some form validation to prevent this issue.

example:

```
def clean_ean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['ean']
    if "fred@example.com" not in data:
        raise forms.ValidationError("message")

    # Always return the cleaned data, whether you have changed it or
    # not.
    return data
```

Refer:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
ean = models.BigIntegerField(requried=True)
...
newP = Product(name='Foo')
```

This result may be what you want.